# Adding multiple operands in an arithmetic expression in a Java String

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

So far, I have this code that parses two different <del>strings</del> operands into double and adds them together

How can I modify it so that it can add any number of <del>strings</del> operands?

```
double addMultipleDigits(String exp)
    {
        ArrayList<Double> wholeExpression  = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double answer = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
        {
          if(exp.charAt(i)=='+')
          {
            answer=Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i-1, i)) + Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1, i+2));
            wholeExpression.add(answer);
            System.out.println(wholeExpression.get(0));

          }         
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: Can there be a "-" in `exp` too?

Comment: Agreed, is this method going to be expanded to try and be a calculator of sorts, or anything like that?

Comment: The OP is asking to add any number of *operands* in the single string argument - not for the function to accept any number of Java String objects.

Comment: So [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646572/java-rpn-calculator)'s accepted answer is probably useful.

Answer (score 8):

Change the signature to add a varargs.

```
double addMultipleDigits(String... exp)
```

It can be handled in the method's body as a String array.

Comment: Awesome, never knew how to do this before, was always saying to myself I'd look it up...

Comment: Note for user2297666 : with this notation, if you want to put other arguments, "String..." must be the last

Comment: [Java 7 Varargs docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: I have to have the parameter as one continuous string. i.e. 1+5+10

Comment: @user2297666 Do they *have* to be passed in as a single `String`? Or can you not just append each separate `String` in the array to one `String` at the beginning of your method?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you want [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
double addMultipleDigits(String... expressions)
```

The `expressions` parameter here is just a regular array, so you can still use `.length` etc.

Then you can call it either with an array explicitly, or just several arguments:

```
addMultipleDigits("123", "456");
```

Comment: I have to have the parameter as one continuous string. i.e. 1+5+10

Comment: @user2297666: Why didn't you say so to start with? Your question specifically asked for multiple strings. So, you can get one string... what is your question, *exactly*?

Answer (score 2):

Parsing and evaluating expressions is something not to be done without the correct theoretical foundation (I never thought I'd say that). You need to learn about lexers and parsers, and how they work. Once you have produced a parse tree from your input you can evaluate it, or evaluate it inline.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers says the correct info to use variable number of arguement. But accorind to your comment it seems you want to have the parameter in a single string like 1+5+10.

It is better if you use varargs but it is must for you to use single string then you can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). For Example

```
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1+2+3","+");
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         String s = st.nextToken(); // s is the separated string.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info here [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

```
 void foo(String... args) 
 {
    for (String s : args) 
    {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
 }
```