# Infix to Postfix using stacks

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or not. I'm trying to convert infix equation to postfix equation like:

```
(3 + 4) * 2
```

in postfix is:

```
4 3 + 2 *
```

I'm trying to do this all in one method if possible.

Right now I'm getting an arrayoutofbounds error so the I'm popping in the wrong place or something.

Here's the infixtopostfix method.

```
public void InfixToPostfix(String f) {
    Stacked postfix = new Stacked(100);
    Stacked op = new Stacked(100);
    char c;
    String fix = f;
    //String out = "";
    int out = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fix.length(); i++) {
        c = fix.charAt(i);

        if (c != '+' || c != '*' || c != '-' || c != '/' || c != '(' || c != ')') {
            // out += c;
            postfix.push(c);
        } 
        else if (c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '-' || c == '/') {
            if (c != ')') {
                op.push(c);
            } else {
                out = (char) op.pop();
                s.push(out);
            }
            out = (char) op.pop();
            System.out.println("THE POSTFIX = " + out)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework or you otherwise should/want to come up with your own solution, you should look at the shunting yard algorithm.

Comment: I would make `s` a local variable. What do you see when you step through your code with a debugger. I would find the simplest expression which shows a problem.

Comment: Play computer with the input string, a piece of paper, and a pencil... what is happening when you hit the first few characters of input? Is that what you really want?

Comment: yea the arrayexceptionbounds error was pointing to the out += s.pop() right underneath the first if(statement)

Comment: I deleted it but gettiing the wrong output now obviously

Comment: What is it with all these xfix to yfix questions these last few days? Anyways you should think about some more test cases I'd propose `(3 +          5 * 6)*2` for one, then handle blanks somewhat sensibly and then look at the shunting yard algorithm as denlan already said.

Comment: yea I've already put over 20 hours on this program which is way more than it should take. I had to do 3 different things: 1. test for parentheses 2. postfixevaluation and 3. infix to postfix. I got it all done but infix to postfix and I'm just frustrated and trying to get done. Stacks always gave me trouble I dont know why.

Comment: I understand the theory but actually writing it I get completely lost.

Comment: You need to throw all this away and look up recursive descent expression parsing, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

```
  public class Postfix {

   private int priority(char ch) {
    if (ch == '^')
     return 3;
    if (ch == '/' || ch == '*')
     return 2;
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
     return 1;
    return 0;
   }

   public String toPostfix(String in ) {

    String copy = in +")";
    Stack s = new Stack(copy.length());
    s.push('(');

    int i, l = copy.length();
    char ch;

    String r = "";
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

     ch = copy.charAt(i);
     if (Character.isLetter(ch) == true)
      r += ch;

     else if (ch == '(')
      s.push(ch);

     else if (ch == ')') {
      while (s.seeTop() != '(')
       r += s.popSeeTop();

      s.pop();

     } else {
      while (priority(ch) <= priority(s.seeTop()))
       r += s.popSeeTop();

      s.push(ch);
     }
    }
    return r;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I'm the only methods I allowed to use is push, pop, isstackempty. Not the built-in methods. I had to create my own. so seeTop() can't be used

Comment: u can declare the top and stack array as public in your stack class and then instead for seeTop() use s.stk[top] where stk is the name of the stack array

Comment: how would you write a peek() method , not the built in one though

Comment: create a variable to store the topmost element and then pop the stack(make sure it does not return anything) and return the variable value. This is your peek() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class InfixToPostfix {

Stack operatorStack = new Stack();

public String toPrefix(String expression) {
    expression="("+expression+")";
    int i;      
    char token;
    String output = "";
    for (i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        token = expression.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(token) == true)
            output += token;
        else if (token == '(')
            operatorStack.push(token);
        else if (token == ')') {
            char seeTop;
            while ((seeTop = seeTop()) != '(') {
                output += seeTop;
                popSeeTop();
            }

            operatorStack.pop();
        } else {
            while (priority(token) <= priority(seeTop())) {
                output += seeTop();
                popSeeTop();
            }
            operatorStack.push(token);
        }
    }
    return output;

}

private int priority(char operator) {
    if (operator == '^')
        return 3;
    if (operator == '/' || operator == '*')
        return 2;
    if (operator == '+' || operator == '-')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

private Character seeTop() {
    if(!operatorStack.empty())
        return (Character) operatorStack.peek();
    else
        return '0';
}

private void popSeeTop() {
    if(!operatorStack.empty())
        operatorStack.pop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Convert arithmetic from infix to postfix
 *
 * @example 1 * ( 12 + 23 ) - ( 4 / 5 ) => 1 12 23 + * 4 5 / -
 * @author  Yong Su
 */
import java.util.Stack; 
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

class InfixToPostfix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String infix = "1 * ( 12 + 23 ) - ( 4 / 5 )";
        String postfix = convert(infix);
        System.out.println(postfix);
    }

    /**
     * Perform the conversion
     *
     * @param expression Arithmetic infix format
     */
    public static String convert(String expression) {
        // Use StringBuilder to append string is faster than
        // String concatenation
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Use a stack to track operations
        Stack<Character> op = new Stack<Character>();

        // Convert expression string to char array
        char[] chars = expression.toCharArray();

        // The length of expression character
        int N = chars.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            char ch = chars[i];

            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                // Number, simply append to the result
                while (Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
                    sb.append(chars[i++]);
                }
                // Use space as delimiter
                sb.append(' ');
            } else if (ch == '(') {
                // Left parenthesis, push to the stack
                op.push(ch);
            } else if (ch == ')') {
                // Right parenthesis, pop and append to the result until meet the left parenthesis
                while (op.peek() != '(') {
                    sb.append(op.pop()).append(' ');
                }
                // Don't forget to pop the left parenthesis out
                op.pop();
            } else if (isOperator(ch)) {
                // Operator, pop out all higher priority operators first and then push it to the stack
                while (!op.isEmpty() && priority(op.peek()) >= priority(ch)) {
                    sb.append(op.pop()).append(' ');
                }
                op.push(ch);
            }
        }

        // Finally pop out whatever left in the stack and append to the result
        while(!op.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(op.pop()).append(' ');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Check if a character is an operator
     */
    private static boolean isOperator(char ch) {
        return ch == '^' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '+' || ch == '-';
    }

    /**
     * Define the operator priority
     */
    private static int priority(char operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case '^' : return 3;
            case '*' :
            case '/' : return 2;
            case '+' :
            case '-' : return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Here we assume that the arithmetic expression has to be intact, otherwise "while (op.peek() != '(') will receive "java.util.EmptyStackException" error.

Comment: Also, String concatenation is very slow, should consider using StringBuilder append() function.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a particularly elegant and simple implementation of what you're trying to do, using simple `Stacks`

```
public class InfixToPostfix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if      (s.equals("+")) stack.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("*")) stack.push(s);
            else if (s.equals(")")) StdOut.print(stack.pop() + " ");
            else if (s.equals("(")) StdOut.print("");
            else                    StdOut.print(s + " ");
        }
        StdOut.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not handle operator precedence.