# Java design pattern to keep a method name in a property file

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have property file(key/value) pair from where I currently read a value against a key and display that value as it is in the UI .

The complexity have increased,Now the value is more dynamic based on some formula. The formula includes a variable parameter whose value  I will get at run time.

Is there any java design pattern to design this scenario .

I was thinking to put a method name in the property file against a key.

Now I will read the key and fetch the method name . This method will calculate the value for that particular key.

Please let me know your suggestion

Comment: The design pattern is "write a parser / tree expression evaluator" ... or "embed an existing expression interpretter".

Comment: You may use usual serialization and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320891/java-rpn-reverse-polish-notation-infix-to-postfix

Comment: Solutions like MVEL or spring EL will help you.

Comment: @AmitParashar MVEL and EL have serious security issues which maybe fine for his use case but for general user input they are not safe.

Comment: @AdamGent, Agreed. As long the formula is maintained in a property file, it should be fine. In case the formula  is also passed by user input, there is a risk. You must be from OWASP :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any java design pattern to design this scenario .

I don't know if there is a pattern.

---

If I understand your question right I can explain **what I do usually**.

- Insert localizable strings in my properties values
  *I usually use `#number#`*
- Replace it later when variables are resolved

Little example:

**messages.properties**

```
name.of.key = sum of #0# + #1# = #2#
```

Then I read the value from and replace the `#num#` with appropiated values (***NOTE:*** here is in the same method for shortenes, but I use an external `replace` method):

```
public void printSum(int n1, int n2) {
    String myString = messageSource("name.of.key", Locale.getDefault(), null, null));
    myString.replace("#0#", String.valueOf(n1));
    myString.replace("#1#", String.valueOf(n2));
    myString.replace("#2#", String.valueOf(n1+n2));
    System.out.println(myString);
}
```

**OUTPUT `printSum(1,2);`**

```
sum of 1 + 2 = 3
```

Comment: Upvote for noting that design does not always come in patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java built-in [JavaScript engine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) to evaluate expressions. To match the spirit more closely, you can use JSON for properties.

If security is important, you need to provide the [class filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ClassFilter.html). It can be very simple and restrictive as you only need to evaluate trivial expressions. The example on class filter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793089/secure-nashorn-js-execution).

Comment: I would hesitate to recommend this solution because it creates a vulnerability to injection attacks.   With this change, the developer must now attend to the security of the key,value pairs.

Comment: It is very easy to restrict the JavaScript if this is an issue. I have edited the question explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) would make here a great fit.

It is a parser generator. You give it grammar as an input and in return it provides you with a parser.

You can use the parser to transform the textual formula into a parsed tree representation. After that, you can run a visitor to evaluate each of the nodes. You just write some simple function to implement the behavior, such as:

```
public Double visitAdd(AntlrNode left, AntlrNode right) {
    Double left = visit(left);
    Double right = viist(right);

    return left + right;
}
```

The grammar is very close to the familiar BNF notation. You just describe how your formula strings are. For example:

```
formula : left '+' right;
left: Number;
right: Number;
Number: [0-9]+;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strategy pattern putting the method/algorithm name in the property file:

```
public interface IFormula{
    public int formula(int a, int b);
}
public class Sum implements IFormula{
    public int formula(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Then you can select the method getting the name from a property file:

```
public static Strategy getStrategy(Name name) {
    switch (name) {
        case SUM:
            return new Sum();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Except for the minor issues of operator precedence and parentheses.

Comment: This is just one example of the strategy pattern. The question does not specify the formula...

Comment: The question is entitled 'Java design pattern to keep a formula in a property file', and you haven't answered it correctly except for trivial cases, and without specifying its limitations.

Comment: But  now, he fetch the method name from the property file not a formula... Infact he has proposed to insert the method name in the property file

Comment: It doesn't make any difference to your answer. The Strategy pattern is not a parsing algorithm, and cannot be used in this situation other than subject to extreme constraints.

Comment: @Programmer Is there any java design pattern to design this scenario.

Comment: I agree with @Valerio. The question wasn't about parsing, and as long as putting the formula itself into a property value is not a requirement, the strategy pattern will fit nicely. (I would just use the strategy implementation's class name instead of an enum, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to refactor your map so that the value type is a functional interface whose method accepts an arbitrary parameter.  For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ValueType<R> {
    R eval(Object param);
}
```

This solution (or a variant of it) would enable you to associate a lambda with your keys rather than a fixed value.  The performance of a lambda ought to be much better than a run-time parser while still affording you the flexibility to make the associated value depend upon a run-time argument.

This solution should also be less vulnerable to injection attacks than a solution based on run-time parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want a name for the pattern... the pattern is called: **[Domain Specific Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)**.

And again if you want to remain in the realms of abstract patterns and design you can peruse [Martin Fowlers discussion on the topic at length](http://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/).

Needless to say their are a metric ton of tools that solve the above pattern (including some of the answers here).

The other pattern which I highly recommend you **NOT** do is use a general purpose language that has an evaluator (ie Javascript, EL, Groovy, etc). This generally has security issues and performance issues (of course there are exceptions).