# Convert an arithmetic String into a double Java

Tags: java, android, string, type-conversion, double

I'm making a calculator app and I need a way to convert a String (the numbers that the user click that appear on the display) into a double.
For example this is a String:

`String stringNumber="12.5/2.4+12";`

And I need to put this expression into a double and calculate the result.

I have tried in this way:

```
double number= Double.parseDouble(stringNumber);
```

But obviously it doesn't work. It's because there are signs inside the expression. I need to calculate the result before the assignment.

Comment: do you need to code the algorithm yourself (ie is it some sort of assignment)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Use exp4j there is even a tutorial for you http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/android-simple-calculator.html

Comment: You're nowhere near a solution.  You will need a parser in general to handle an arithmetic expression.

Comment: You need to implement a parser. Probably the most popular way of doing it is with Reverse Polish Notation. Here is related question and example implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320891/java-rpn-reverse-polish-notation-infix-to-postfix

Comment: @Luke Unless it is a parser exercise, the OP should not implement a parser. Java parsers for simple arithmetic expressions already exist. The OP should pick one and use it.

Comment: He can pick one but he can implement one  for fun and experience ;)

Comment: It isn't a parser exercise, i can use a library.  I'm trying the exp4j and for now it works well. Then i will try the Reverse Polish Notation. :)